# how i can know the width of div element

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the width in pixels of a HTML `<div>` element in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `divElement.offsetWidth || divElement.clientWidth`

and also you might as well want to try `divElement.style.width`

Note: divElement is the DOM element of your div which can be obtained by `document.getElementById("yourDivId")`